# Validate userform textbox to fractional

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that should accept only fractional values, such as 15/35 , 1-4/5 and so on.

For numerical values there's a method IsNumeric.
Is there anything I can use for Fractional numbers?

I tried LIKE method in Change event.

```vb
If (Me.txt_Fractional Like "00/00") Then
    fr = Me.txt_Fractional.value
Else
    Me.txt_Fractional = ""
End If
```

Comment: Regex or `Like`.

Comment: or application.Evaluate the input and test that output to see if it is a number.

Comment: ... or take two neighbour input fields (marked by a slash label in between) which can be evaluated separately :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with 2 functions. The first one is for textbox Change event and another is for textbox Exit event.

```
Function validate_fraction(val As String) As Boolean
    validd = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    validd = Evaluate(val)
    On Error GoTo 0
     If Not IsError(validd) Or Right(val, 1) = "/" Then
            validate_fraction = True
    Else
        validate_fraction = False
    End If
End Function

Function validate_fraction_exit(val As String) As Boolean
    validd = 0
    On Error Resume Next
        validd = Evaluate(val)
    On Error GoTo 0
        If Not IsError(validd) And InStr(val, "/") > 0 And Not InStr(val, ".") > 0 Then
            validate_fraction_exit = True
        Else
            validate_fraction_exit = False
        End If

End Function
```